# How to enable Google hangouts plugin in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, google-hangouts

How do you enable Google Hangouts in Chrome on Ubuntu 16?

I have a Gmail account open in Chrome, and when I hover over the phone icon in Gchat, it says "Please enable Hangouts to make and receive in this browser". It then links to [this page](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?hl=en), which allows me to download a .deb file to install the plugin, which installed fine. However, even after restarting my browser, Chrome still shows the same messages saying the Hangouts plugin is not installed.

Answer (score -3):

Chrome doesn't support ActiveX controls or NPAPI plugins, so the plugin you downloaded won't work. You can try reading the text on the bottom of [the page you linked.](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?hl=en)

Instead, you can try to use the [Hangouts extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd).

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion. Nothing on that page mentions ActiveX or NPAPI. The idea that Google would recommend the installation of a Linux package which would not work with any known browser on Linux, much less Chrome, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Cerin You might want to take a look at this: https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation Plus, you don't even need the plugin: http://www.omgchrome.com/google-hangouts-chrome-plugin-free-2/

Comment: @Cerin Also, did you read the fine print on the page? http://imgur.com/I2YnL3F